# How to store a 2D array in another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have several arrays in C# in this form:

```
int[ ,] A1 = new int[3, 3]
{   { 0, 0, 0},
    { 1, 1, 1},
    { 0, 0, 0}
};
```

and am interested in finding out how I can store them in another array so that I can access these 2 dimensional arrays.

Thanks

Comment: array of array is basically 3 dimensional array isnt it

Comment: Do you know what a `List` is?

Comment: I would use a `List<T>` however if you want to define a dynamic array you can do the following and it will work 
`int[,] A1 = { };
  A1 = new int[3, 3]
  {   { 0, 0, 0},
  { 1, 1, 1},
  { 0, 0, 0}
   };`

Comment: my example also works with a List when using a var A1 = {} because you can call the `A1 = List<T>.ToArray()`  you should play around with as well as understand the power that you have at your finger tips vs trying to get someone to pump out an answer for you. I know that many have never seen what I have posted and many that I have worked with have challenged me on if it would compile or not because we have all learned from past coding that we should always initialize arrays and length...etc.. but that's not always the case

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your question and the answer given. It didn't work for me either, given I had the same question. I wanted to put my uninitialized 2D arrays from my data access in an array so I can see if said array exists on another form. That being said, this is what worked for me:

```
public string[,][,] arrayStrings2D = {
    { lines, ItemName, Description, strDescriptionsShowStock, strNameShowStock, 
     StockItemNames, inventoryList, ItemNameAppend, DescriptionAppend, 
     inventoryListAppend}
    };
```

And a little more context:

```
static string[,] lines = 
   {
       { },
       { },
       { },
       { },
       { }
   };

   //-------------------------------------------------------------------
   //These will hold the data
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------
   static int[,] Quantity = { { } };
   static string[,] ItemName = { { } };
   static string[,] Description = { { } };
   static float[,] Weight = { { } };
   static float[,] Cost = { { } };

  static int[,] QuantityAppend = { { } };
   static string[,] ItemNameAppend = { { } };
   static string[,] DescriptionAppend = { { } };
   static float[,] WeightAppend = { { } };
   static float[,] CostAppend = { { } };
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------

   static string[] strInventoryItems = new string[5];
   static string[] NameInternal_SetInventory = Inventory.GetName();

   static string[,] strDescriptionsShowStock = { { } };
   static string[,] strNameShowStock = { { } };
   static float[,] fltCostShowStock = {{ } };
   static int[,] intQTYShowStock = { { } };
   static float[,] fltAvgWeightShowStock = { { } };
   static string[,] inventoryList = { { } };
   static string[,] inventoryListAppend = { { } };
   static String[,] StockItemNames = { { } };
   

   //holds the actual variable data
   public string[,][,] arrayStrings2D = {

       { lines, ItemName, Description, strDescriptionsShowStock,
         strNameShowStock, StockItemNames, inventoryList, ItemNameAppend,
         DescriptionAppend, inventoryListAppend}
       };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare an array of multi dimensional arrays using:

```
var arrays = new int[length][,];
```

Then you need to initialize each array, using either:

```
arrays[0] = new int[3,3];
```

Or:

```
arrays[0] = A1;
```

Comment: new int[length][,] is redundent, [,,,] should be used

Comment: @Steve No it's not - `int[length][,]` lets you get/set an entire 2-D array in one statement, whereas to get/set two dimensions of a 3-D array you'd have to set each value independently.